# Bottom Tab Navigator background image

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

Im using `React Navigation 3`. Currently I have a `bottomTabNavigator` in my project. I want to set a background image or art for it. My header was pretty much straight forward because I used a property called `headerBackground` and I passed a react component to it and it works, but its not the case for bottomTab.

I managed to make it work somehow by using `tabBarComponent` so the image renders ok, but the problem is that my tabs disappear.

Is there a proper way to set a background image to `tabNavigator`?

Here is my current `tabNavigator` code:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { createBottomTabNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import Profile from "../components/Profile";
import { Image, View } from 'react-native';

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator(
    {
        Profile: {
            screen: Profile,
            navigationOptions: {
                title: 'Home',
                tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
                    <Image
                        source={require('../../images/home-ico.png')}
                        style={{width: 25, height: 25, resizeMode: 'contain'}}
                    />
                )
            }
        },
        Partidos: {
            screen: Profile,
            navigationOptions: {
                title: 'Home',
                tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
                    <Image
                        source={require('../../images/home-ico.png')}
                        style={{width: 25, height: 25, resizeMode: 'contain'}}
                    />
                )
            }
        },
        Grupos: {
            screen: Profile,
            navigationOptions: {
                title: 'Home',
                tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
                    <Image
                        source={require('../../images/home-ico.png')}
                        style={{width: 25, height: 25, resizeMode: 'contain'}}
                    />
                )
            }
        },
        Reserva: {
            screen: Profile,
            navigationOptions: {
                title: 'Home',
                tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
                    <Image
                        source={require('../../images/home-ico.png')}
                        style={{width: 25, height: 25, resizeMode: 'contain'}}
                    />
                )
            }
        }
    },
    {
        tabBarOptions:{
            style: {
                backgroundColor: '#c2b464',
            },
            showLabel: false
        },
        tabBarComponent: props =>{
            return(
                <View>
                    <Image
                        style={{ width: '100%', height: 50 }}
                        source={ require('../../images/tabs-bg.png')}/>
                </View>
            );
        }
    }
);

export default createAppContainer(Tab);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tabBarComponent: props =><BottomNavigator {...props}/>
```

Just make the component and create the Icon or Text in and render it.
Under component u can navigate to other screen by `this.props.navigation.navigate('desirescreen-route');`